# Unable to convert BuiltinString to JSON

Tags: plutus, script, datum, on-chain

I would like to include a `BuiltinString` in a datum but am unable to do so as `BuiltinString` has neither a `FromJSON` nor a `ToJSON` instance. Is there an alternative to implementing these instances by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BuiltinString` has no `ToData` instance so it cannot be used as Datum. One option is to `encodeUtf8` and use the `BuiltinByteString`. Not sure why you want to use JSON though.